# Google Picker with AccessToken not working

Tags: javascript, php, google-authentication, google-picker, google-php-sdk

I can't seem to get Google Picker working. I have authenticated my user using the [PHP League Oauth Provider](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-google)

After authenticating, an accessToken for my user looks something like this;

> ya67.Fi_dfioriogneegroig7Czdy54z0sdfdvnfr9fn38n3n93

This is my Javascript and HTML code for rendering the picker;

```
<a href="{{ appContextInstallId }}/authenticate" class="btn info">
    <i class="icon-bolt"></i> Authenticate
</a>

<button onClick="createPicker()">Add a new document</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var developerKey = 'erteetr43gg-V34y4httytjyjytjyttyjyjyjjy';
    var clientId = "373498750987-5dsfwerrwewerweewrl.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    var appId = "373498750987"

    var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];
    var pickerApiLoaded = false;

    // Use the Google API Loader script to load the google.picker script.

    // Create and render a Picker object for searching images.
    function createPicker() {
        var view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
            .setAppId(appId)
            .setOAuthToken("{{ token|escape }}")
            .addView(view)
            .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
            .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .build();

        picker.setVisible(true);
    }

    // A simple callback implementation.
    function pickerCallback(data) {
        // makes an ajax call....
    }
</script>

<!-- The Google API Loader script. -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My accessToken is available at `{{ token|escape }}`.

When I try and click the "Add a new document" button, I get the following error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined at createPicker

I don't know why this is. Am I not using the access token correctly?

By the way, I *need* to take of the accessToken business using server side technology because I have multiple sub-domains and you can't wildcard them in Google Dev Console. Therefore, I can't just use a standard example [like this one](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/) to authenticate via client side.

PS - Obviously those aren't my real tokens/secrets in the code block above. They have been changed.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [Google Loader Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/loader/) for a more detailed information on how to load Google APIs.

As discussed,

> To load the APIs, include the following script in the header of your web page.
>
> `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`
>
> Next, load the Google API with google.load(module, version), where
>
> - `module` calls the specific API module you wish to use on your page.
> - `version` is the version number of the module you wish to load.
>
> After you call `google.load`, you can use all of the loaded modules in your web page.

Lastly, you may want to check [Available APIs](https://developers.google.com/loader/#available-apis), specifically [Picker API Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/) and make sure that you haven't missed important functions when creating a `Picker` object.

Hope that helps!